# VS Designer question. How to change parent control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-controls

VS beginner question. How to change parent control of a control? Example. I have TabControl on form, aligned to fit the all form. I have double clicked of toolStrip control to create menu and instead of the form toolStrip was added to TabControl. How to move toolStrip from the TabControl to the Form. I can use copy/paste but that not always works.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In the menu select View -> Other Windows -> Document Outline. In that window you see the hierarchical view of your components. Drag the controls to their new parent.